# How to return a non default reply in AWS API gateway without raising an Exception?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm running a service that uses the AWS API Gateway. There is an endpoint that is integrated using a lambda function written in Python. This endpoint has several different response codes, for example, 200, 201, 400, 404.

I'm aware we can generate different response codes by raising an exception and catching the error regex in API Gateway. An example in python would be:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    raise Exception('404_not_found')
```

And then configure in the API Gateway in following way:

[image: gateway config]

This will then return a 404 response code. The problem with this approach is that my log will be full of errors. Even when I want to throw a different response than the default one, like a 201 in this case, I believe I would have to raise an Exception.

This results in difficult monitoring, where I have a bunch of exceptions in my logs which are actually just natural behavior. My question, therefore, is if I can generate a non default response without raising an Exception when using Python lambdas and the API Gateway?

Answer (score 1):

In OpenAPI you can use `x-amazon-apigateway-gateway-responses` at API root level. Similar way you can do in Python. You can refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-gateway-responses-in-swagger.html